# Keyframe opacity in certain time stamps (%)

Tags: css, css-animations, slide, keyframe

I´ve done a slideshow which automatically changes the images trough a keyframe animation in CSS. Now I have elements which should change their opacity in the same rhythm as the images in my slideshow do.

My HTML Code:

```
  <section class="slideshow">
        <div class="colors-bg white-bg">
          <div class="color-wrapper">
            <div class="color bluerocratic-bg"></div>
            <div class="color blue-dacnis-bg"></div>
            <div class="color lamiaceae-bg"></div>
            <div class="color acid-pops-bg"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="slideshow-media">

          <div class="left">
            <div class="slideshow-wrapper">

              <div class="img">
                <img src="img/slideshow_verkauf.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="img">
                <img src="img/slideshow_werkstatt.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="img">
                <img src="img/slideshow_lastenrad-leasing.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="img">
                <img src="img/slideshow_kinderrad-abo.jpg" alt="">
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="right">

            <div class="slideshow-wrapper-text">

              <div class="text-wrapper">
                <div class="textbox">
                  <h2 class="margin-btm-s">„Zweirad für Einmalige“</h2>
                  <p class="margin-btm-lg">Sie wollen ein Fahrrad für alle Tage, stadt- und landtauglich?</p>
                  <button class="hero-btn svg-btn dark-grey-bg dark-grey-bs">Mehr dazu
                    <svg id="a" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 26.21 12.99">
                      <g id="b" transform="translate(0 0.53)"><path id="c" class="e" d="M0,6.5H25.15"/><path id="d" class="e" d="M19.19,.53l5.97,5.97-5.97,5.97"/></g></svg>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="text-wrapper">
                <div class="textbox">
                  <h2 class="margin-btm-s">„Damit das Rad rund läuft“</h2>
                  <p class="margin-btm-lg">So sind Sie sicher und lange mit Ihrem Drahtesel unterwegs!</p>
                  <button class="hero-btn svg-btn dark-grey-bg dark-grey-bs">Mehr dazu
                    <svg id="a" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 26.21 12.99">
                      <g id="b" transform="translate(0 0.53)"><path id="c" class="e" d="M0,6.5H25.15"/><path id="d" class="e" d="M19.19,.53l5.97,5.97-5.97,5.97"/></g></svg>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="text-wrapper">
                <div class="textbox">
                  <h2 class="margin-btm-s">„Kaufen war gestern, jetzt ist leasen angesagt!“</h2>
                  <p class="margin-btm-lg">Wählen Sie das jeweils passende Lastenrad für Ihren Transport.</p>
                  <button class="hero-btn svg-btn dark-grey-bg dark-grey-bs">Mehr dazu
                    <svg id="a" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 26.21 12.99">
                      <g id="b" transform="translate(0 0.53)"><path id="c" class="e" d="M0,6.5H25.15"/><path id="d" class="e" d="M19.19,.53l5.97,5.97-5.97,5.97"/></g></svg>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="text-wrapper">
                <div class="textbox">
                  <h2 class="margin-btm-s">„Wenn das Fahrrad mitwächst“</h2>
                  <p class="margin-btm-lg">So hat Ihr Kind immer das richtige Rad!</p>
                  <button class="hero-btn svg-btn dark-grey-bg dark-grey-bs">Mehr dazu
                    <svg id="a" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 26.21 12.99">
                      <g id="b" transform="translate(0 0.53)"><path id="c" class="e" d="M0,6.5H25.15"/><path id="d" class="e" d="M19.19,.53l5.97,5.97-5.97,5.97"/></g></svg>
                  </button>
              </div>
            </div>

            </div>

          </div>
      </section>
```

My CSS code for the slideshow looks like this:

```
.slideshow-wrapper {
  height: 400%;
  width: 50vw;
  position: absolute;
  animation: 40s slider_animation ease-in-out infinite;
}

.slideshow-wrapper-text {
  height: 400%;
  width: 50vw;
  position: absolute;
  animation: 40s slider_animation ease-in-out infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slider_animation {
  0% { top: 0%; }
  22.5% { top: 0%; }

  28.5% { top: -100%; }
  45% { top: -100%; }

  51% { top: -200%; }
  67.5% { top: -200%; }

  76.5% { top: -300%; }
  90% { top: -300%; }

  100% { top: 0%; }
}
```

Is there any possibility to create an opacity animation with keyframes like I did with the image position. It should loop infinite like my slideshow.

Here´s my example:
[image: Example]

The images as well as the text beside are sliding respectively to the next. My goal is to show only one color per image/text slide, the remaining colors should have a lower opacity. When the slide changes the color opacity of the next changes and the latest gets back to a lower opacity.

It has to be css only unfortunately :/

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you show your HTML structure (and any relevant CSS) as it may depend on the relationship between the bullets and the images as to whether it is easy to keep them in step timing-wise.

Comment: Hey thank you for your help! I added the html and the relevant css

Comment: Thanks, I think the answer (in order to be certain of getting the animations keeping in step) is to put the color bullets on using a before pseudo element which moves with each slide. I will look at this further in a few hours if you still need help.

Comment: Do you want the opacity change on those circles to be animated or just when the second image comes into view the first circle is immediately at lower opacity and the second circle at opacity 1 and so on?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand your goal. Do you want something like this?

```css
.slideshow-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50vw;
  background:lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  animation: 5s slider_animation ease-in-out infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slider_animation {
  0% { opacity: 100%; }
  22.5% { opacity: 0%; }

  28.5% { opacity: 100%; }
  45% { opacity: 0%; }

  51% { opacity: 100%; }
  67.5% { opacity: 0%; }

  76.5% { opacity: 100%; }
  90% { opacity: 0%; }

  100% { opacity: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-wrapper">

</div>
```

**Update**
I think you should make something like this according to what you say in the comments:

```css
.bullets{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.bullets div{
  font-size:0;
  padding:5px;
  margin:5px;
  width:10px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:blue;
  animation: 8s slider_animation ease-in-out infinite;
}
.bullets div:nth-child(1){
  animation-delay:0;
}
.bullets div:nth-child(2){
  animation-delay:1s;
}
.bullets div:nth-child(3){
  animation-delay:2s;
}

.bullets div:nth-child(4){
  animation-delay:3s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slider_animation {
  0% { background:blue; }
  22.5% { background:lightblue; }

  28.5% { background:lightgreen; }
  45% { background:green;}

  51% { background:blue; }
  67.5% { background:lightblue; }

  76.5% { background:lightgreen; }
  90% { background:green; }

  100% { background:blue; }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-wrapper">
  <div class="bullets">
    <div>bullet 1</div>
    <div>bullet 2</div>
    <div>bullet 3</div>
    <div>bullet 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First thank you for your help!! Sorry for my unclear question, I edited it and added a picture of the situation I want to create. I hope its more understandable now.

Comment: you're welcome. It is better, but it isn't clear yet. Do you want to change the slider's bullets colors orderly?

Comment: exactly thats my goal!

Comment: I Updated it. I hope it to be helpful.

Comment: Thank you! its gettin in the right direction. What do I have to adjust that only one color is full satured and the remaining 3 are desatured? The colors standing for the different categories of the site. Every image stands for one category, so the color. Thats why I want to have always the active category color satured.

Comment: I'm not sure. I think you should write a more advanced animation for it. Of course, there are more solutions and ways to do it. But I could help you better if I have more information about your project. Maybe this way doesn't be reasonable as your goal.